# Forward Declaration using for a template method

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Why do I get an error when using a template method with a forward declared class? I don't actually need a definition of this class, only a declaration. Or maybe I have misunderstood how it actually works? Do I really need to include a corresponding .h file of class `B`?

Edited:
And why then does forward declaration of class SomeInterface work with `static_assert` if I actually include "B.h"?

**I want to achieve forward declaration to use template method without including ".h" files**

Question after Kevin reply:

bar() method is actually needed for a Template Method Pattern, so there will be like a family of namespace Second. The problem is if I include more ".h" files from namespace Second, doesn't it be less optimized? This bar() method will be executed only once at start of the program

Example code:

```
// A.cpp
#include "A.h"

namespace Second
{
    class SomeInterface;
    class B;
}

namespace First
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        A() = default;

        template <typename M>
        void foo()
        {
            static_assert(std::is_base_of<Second::SomeInterface, M>::value, "You need to use SomeInterface or Derived from it");
        }

        void bar() // -- Template Method Pattern
        {
            foo<Second::B>(); // -- C2139   'Second::B': an undefined class is not allowed as
                      // an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_base_of'
            foo<Second::C>();
            foo<Second::D>();
            //...

        }
    };
}
```

```
// B.cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "SomeInerface.h"

namespace Second
{
    class B : public SomeInterface
    {
    public:
        B() = default;
    };
}
```

If I add this to the A.cpp then it will work fine

```
#include "B.h"
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: It's giving me error on compile time. If I clear line `foo<Second::B>();` it will then work fine

Comment: The given error message seems to indicate that the issue is specific to the use of `std::is_base_of` (in function `foo()`).

Comment: So what's the problem with including `B.h` in `A.cpp`? It sounds like you found your solution already.

Comment: The problem is. Isn't I getting more compilation code when including `B.h` for the `A.cpp` file? I mean, forward declaration was created for that doesn't it? That if you don't need definition use declaration. Or declaration not using inheritance?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me: `C2139   'Second::B': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_base_of'`. You can't use a forward declaration for everything. Sometimes you need the full definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I get an error when using a template method with a forward declared class?

This is not *generally* a problem.

> I don't actually need a definition of this class, only a declaration. Or maybe I have misunderstood how it actually works?

There is no general rule that template parameters need to be complete types, but there are specific cases, and yours is one of them.

> Do I really need to include a corresponding .h file of class B?

In this case, yes.

> And why then does forward declaration work with static_assert?

I'm not sure what you mean.  The only `static_assert` in your code is in template method `First::A::foo()`.  You get an error related to that `static_assert` (though not an assertion failure) when you instantiate the template with a certain template parameter.  In what sense, then, do you think the behavior of the `static_assert` is inconsistent?

The basic problem here is that the `std::is_base_of` template requires its second type argument to be a complete type.  This is in its specifications.  A class type that is (only) forward-declared, with no definition in scope, is not complete.  Therefore, you get an error when you instantiate `First::A::foo<Second::B>` at a point where no definition of `Second::B` is in scope.  That error is recognized before the assertion can be evaluated, so the `static_assert` doesn't factor in except as the context of the error.